# Bash script: Find string in a file and write a subsequent string it into another file

Tags: string, bash

I would like a bash script to find a string in a file and extract subsequent information by writing in into another file. Here is an example of the original content of file foo.txt:

```
    <?xml-stylesheet href="http://www.tib-hannover.de/ext/schema/2007-06-26/browser-view.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><ftx:documentContainer xmlns:ftx="http://www.tib-hannover.de/ext/schema/2007-06-26/fiz-tib-schema.xsd" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tib-hannover.de/ext/schema/2007-06-26/fiz-tib-schema.xsd http://www.tib-hannover.de/ext/schema/2007-06-26/fiz-tib-schema.xsd">
  <document id="TIBKAT:898939593">
    <systemInfo>
      <supplier shortname="tib">Technische Informationsbibliothek (TIB)</supplier>
      <databaseDate>2017-10-10</databaseDate>
      <changeDate>2019-03-10</changeDate>
      <ftxCreationDate>2020-10-12</ftxCreationDate>
      <documentID>898939593</documentID>
      <exportRestricted>false</exportRestricted>
      <searchSpaces mappingCriterionTIBUB="datapool" mappingCriterionTN="gmp">
        <searchSpace>TIBUB</searchSpace>
        <searchSpace>TN</searchSpace>
      </searchSpaces>
      <licenseModels>
        <licenseModel>com</licenseModel>
      </licenseModels>
    </systemInfo>
    <formalInfo>
      <documentTypes>
        <documentAdvancedType>
          <documentGenreGroup>
            <documentGenre>
              <documentGenreCode>R</documentGenreCode>
            </documentGenre>
          </documentGenreGroup>
          <documentTypeGroup>
            <documentType>
              <documentTypeCode>PR</documentTypeCode>
            </documentType>
          </documentTypeGroup>
        </documentAdvancedType>
      </documentTypes>
      <documentLanguages>
        <documentLanguage>
          <languageCodes>
            <code iso="639-1">de</code>
            <code iso="639-2">ger</code>
          </languageCodes>
        </documentLanguage>
      </documentLanguages>
      <identifiers>
        <identifier type="ppn">898939593</identifier>
        <identifier type="contract">19G13008B</identifier>
        <identifier type="contract">01148408</identifier>
        <identifier type="firstid">GBV:898939593</identifier>
      </identifiers>
      <locations>
        <location subtype="toc" type="url">http://www.gbv.de/dms/tib-ub-hannover/898939593.pdf</location>
      </locations>
      <localHoldings>
        <localHolding database="TIBKAT">
          <identifier type="epn">1714397041</identifier>
          <creationDate>2017-11-27</creationDate>
          <selectionKey>z</selectionKey>
          <location type="tibShelfmark">F 17 B 2775</location>
          <loanIndicator>u</loanIndicator>
          <licenseModels>
            <licenseModel>com</licenseModel>
          </licenseModels>
        </localHolding>
      </localHoldings>
      <sizes>
        <size unit="unknown">35 Blätter</size>
      </sizes>
    </formalInfo>
    <bibliographicInfo dependent="false">
      <dc:title>VertiModal - Untersuchung und Erprobung einer technischen Lösung zur vertikalen Stapelung (Stacking) von Sattelanhängern in Umschlaganlagen des intermodalen Verkehrs : Schlussbericht zum Verwendungsnachweis : Laufzeit des Vorhabens: 01.10.2013-30.06.2016, Berichtszeitraum: 01.10.2013-30.06.2016</dc:title>
      <alternativeTitles>
        <dcterms:alternative>Schlussbericht Projekt VertiModal</dcterms:alternative>
      </alternativeTitles>
      <corporateCreators>
        <corporateCreator>
          <name>dfl duisport facility logistics GmbH</name>
          <corporateIDs>
            <corporateID type="gnd">7784186-4</corporateID>
          </corporateIDs>
        </corporateCreator>
      </corporateCreators>
      <publicationInfo>
        <dcterms:issued>2017</dcterms:issued>
        <publicationPlaces>
          <publicationPlace>[Duisburg]</publicationPlace>
        </publicationPlaces>
        <publicationCountries>
          <publicationCountry code="DE"/>
        </publicationCountries>
        <dc:publisher>[dfl duisport facility logistics GmbH]</dc:publisher>
      </publicationInfo>
      <additionalDocumentInfo>
        <publicationIDInfo>Förderkennzeichen BMBF 19G13008B. - Verbund-Nummer 01148408</publicationIDInfo>
        <publicationIDInfo>Unterschiede zwischen dem gedruckten Dokument und der elektronischen Ressource können nicht ausgeschlossen werden</publicationIDInfo>
      </additionalDocumentInfo>
      <dc:description>Illustrationen, Diagramme</dc:description>
    </bibliographicInfo>
    <relatedInfo>
      <related type="parallel">
        <label>Online-Ausgabe</label>
        <dc:title>VertiModal - Untersuchung und Erprobung einer technischen Lösung zur vertikalen Stapelung (Stacking) von Sattelanhängern in Umschlaganlagen des intermodalen Verkehrs</dc:title>
        <identifier type="ppn">1006045880</identifier>
      </related>
    </relatedInfo>
    <classificationInfo>
      <classifications>
        <classification classificationID="181571811" classificationName="bk">
          <code>55.82</code>
          <entries>
            <entry>Güterverkehr</entry>
          </entries>
        </classification>
        <classification classificationName="linsearch" classificationProcedure="mapping">
          <code>ver</code>
        </classification>
      </classifications>
      <subjects>
        <subject id="4031830-8" type="gnd">
          <dc:subject xml:lang="de">Kombinierter Verkehr</dc:subject>
        </subject>
        <subject id="4010520-9" type="gnd">
          <dc:subject xml:lang="de">Containerverkehr</dc:subject>
        </subject>
        <subject id="4148290-6" type="gnd">
          <dc:subject xml:lang="de">Containerterminal</dc:subject>
        </subject>
        <subject id="4179164-2" type="gnd">
          <dc:subject xml:lang="de">Sattelanhänger</dc:subject>
        </subject>
        <subject id="4186789-0" type="gnd">
          <dc:subject xml:lang="de">Umschlaganlage</dc:subject>
        </subject>
      </subjects>
    </classificationInfo>
    <displayInfo>
      <property name="displayDownload">none</property>
      <property name="displayOrder">true</property>
      <property name="displayGetItem">true</property>
    </displayInfo>
  </document>
</ftx:documentContainer>
```

If the string `classificationName="bk"` is found I would like to extract the subsequent information `55.82` and `Güterverkehr`. These two strings should be written in a partner file foo.tsv separated by tab. How is this done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your provided XML file, the following `xmlstarlet` invocation run in `bash` will print out the matching record in TSV format:

```sh
 xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//classification[@classificationName='bk']" -v 'code[text()]' -o $'\t' -v 'entries/entry[text()]' -nl input.xml
```

resulting in

```
55.82   Güterverkehr
```

You can save that in a file using normal shell output redirection.